# InfoPath 3 DropDown pull inforamtion based on selction

Tags: infopath, filter, external-content-type, dropdown

I'm working on a form and am in need of some assistance.

I used the following [link](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2003/autofill-fields-infopath-dropdown-selection-secondary-data-source.htm), as a reference when I was creating this form  I have three separate drop-downs (Name, Address, Phone Number) When one is selected I want the other to be populated with data based on the selection.

The data is being pulled from a data source and I have filters on the rule for the value to set the other field to (learned this from the link above)

I am able to get to where If I select a person name their address and their phone number will show up in the respective drop-down,

but when I try to apply the same rules to another drop down such as "address" I receive an error.

I believe this is because all the conditions are set to run when a field changes so it creates a loop. I'm not sure which conditions to fill in.

Any help will be greatly appreciated if my question is not clear enough please let me know and I will try to reword it

Comment: what's the error that you received

Comment: @M.Qassas "An error occurred in the form's rules or code. The number of rule actions or the number of calls to the OnAfterChange event for a single update in the data exceeded the maximum limit."

"The rules or code may be causing an infinite loop. To prevent this, ensure that the rule action or event handler does not update the data which causes the same rule action or event handler to execute."

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct the problem by adding in a or conditions have having two set field actions under one rule (which i did not know you could do until today, very new to info path)

Thank You to all who viewed the question.